# Npgsql No such host is known

Tags: docker, .net

[No Such Host Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltsdn.png)

I am getting the Npgsql Exception No Such Host is Known, but it only happens intermittently. This is an error being generated in a .Net application written in C#. It is trying to reach a Postgres database in a docker container on a Linux host on the same LAN. Most of the time the connection is fine, but sometimes this error will pop up. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: 0x80004005 is the completely generic error meaning Windows has no idea what happened. Or at least isn't going to tell you.

Comment: I have the same problem with an web app I created using Blazor / npgsql. Tested also at .Net6 or .Net7 with NPGSQL 6.0.4 or 7.0.4. For me seems that this is happening while I am in home while is not happening when I am in office.